# Cassandra throws SSLFactory.java warning

Tags: ssl, cassandra, jce, datastax-enterprise, datastax

We are using dse 3.1.4 with server_encryption_options to all.

server_encryption_options:

```
internode_encryption: all
keystore: /path/to/.keystore
keystore_password: XXXXXXX
truststore: /path/to/.truststore
truststore_password: XXXXXXX
```

We add the java security libraries to the /lib/security but still we see the continues log of

```
WARN [WRITE-/x.x.x.x] 2013-11-04 22:30:28,398 SSLFactory.java (line 139) Filtering out TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA as it isnt supported by the socket
```

Can any one tell me why this is happening?

Comment: What java security libraries did you add to lib/security? Did you install JDK unlimited cryptography strength policy files?

Comment: local_policy.jar,US_export_policy.jar these are the two jar files we added in the security folder and we are using jre1.6.0_43

Comment: Did you restart the server after adding the jars?

Answer (score 3):

The error message is not related to the the keystore, but rather to the SSL ciphers which your version of Java supports.

It seems the cipher TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA is configured to be used somewhere, but the version of Java that you use does not provide this cipher.

When looking at current versions of Java 7, I see this cipher being reported as available, so you can try to run the same with a newer Java version and see if that prevents this warning.